# Progressive rendering of a webpage in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, rendering

I'm trying to improve the user perception of page load time of some web pages. These web pages take about 5 seconds to complete loading and rendering. The overall time is fine; but on clicking a link to load a page, nothing happens for about 4.5 seconds and then the whole page appears in one shot. This spoils the user experience, since the user is left wondering if anything is happening or not after clicking the link.

As I understand it, browsers are supposed to progressively render web pages as and when the resources available to render portions of the page become available to it. One thing I've seen recommended (by YSlow for eg:) is to put the css in the head and the javascript near the ending body tag - or as near the end of the page as possible. I've done this, but I don't see the initial part of the page rendering and then pausing for the javascript to load. The theory, as I understand it, is that the page will begin rendering progressively once all the CSS is loaded. I also understand that the page will pause rendering when any javascript is being executed/downloaded.

What else can affect progressive rendering on IE, especially on IE7?

Comment: Internet Explorer specifically avoids progressive rendering. They don't want to "*confuse*" the user if content might move around. Images are not displayed until completely downloaded (as opposed to FF/WebKit, the display images as they are received). Tables are not rendered at all until the table's entire content is received. etc. i'm just saying that you will be hitting against a design limit in IE that doesn't exist in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first step may be to understand what's going on on the network side, a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will help you.  In your case, [Timeline display](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/images/sshot-1.png) should be a good starting point.

Comment: Definitely enable Fiddler's streaming mode for this purpose.

Comment: I tried HTTPAnalyser (similar to Fiddler) and it suggests that everything needed to render the page (css + html) is available after about 2 seconds. I'm struggling to figure out what IE7 is doing between 2 seconds and 4 seconds when it starts rendering the page.

Comment: The Developer tool in Chrome has an excellent timeline tool as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that javascript (specifically, some jQuery selectors) were slowing things down and preventing the page from rendering. We first optimized the jQuery code by removing some code which was repeatedly selecting the same elements. Then moved the code down to $.ready so that it executes after the page has loaded.
Overall, this has given us a 2 second boost in page load times as well as allowing more pages to load progressively.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for unclosed tags.
2. Check all images have width and height attributes.

Comment: 1. Checked for unclosed tags - none found. Can you please explain why this will affect progressive rendering tho'?
2. We're unable to put width and height attributes for images because many of these images come from a content management system, some of them are larger than the space available on the page to display it and putting a height and width will distort the image - this is unacceptable to the client. 
Thank you for your answer - it certainly improved my understanding of progressive rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Why not show notifications to users when a link is clicked  that the page is currently in loading state.

You can do this:

`window.onbeforeunload = function(e){ document.body.innerHTML='loading...';/*or even a better content/*  };`

Comment: Nice idea - but unfortunately, our client didn't like it. I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: this would certainly break the back button

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same load problems because of flash videos on a page. Will somebody tell me why oh my God why can't ie just load pages as nicely as firefox does???

If ie went out of business today, all the hours and days and nights I've wasted would be over.

I think it's about time that ie get with the demands of web maasters in 2009 and change the way they load pages.

If java script is used, people without java will see blank spaces.